# upload image while recording? Vimeo

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I want to implement a functionality to upload video to vimeo. I am already using their pull request approach to upload video.

But vimeo and video upload takes almost 20 to 30 seconds to upload and encode video for 30 second video. I want to overcome this time.

I have studied about their resume able or tus approach but it is also working for complete recorded video.

Does vimeo provide any approach to upload video while recording?

I can get binary data of video after every 2 seconds through video js  record (timestamp event). So, i am trying to find a way to upload this binary data to vimeo and marked the video complete after uploading.

Answer (score 0):

As of now it seems that Vimeo doesn't provide the solution for this. I was also encountered with the same requirement while using Vimeo but later I found [Addpipe](https://addpipe.com/) as a solution for it.
Addpipe has the fastest upload time as it starts streaming the data back to their media servers as soon as recording starts.
So final upload time after recording stops is very less no matter how long you are  recording.

Comment: does Addpipe has ability to encode the video for all platforms? Also does addpipe has branding functionality for player and video restriction so that it shouldn't access publically?